# Searching neighbours in BFS for particular node

Tags: java, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am facing an issue with implementing the logic portion within the search method.

All the values are taken as input from the main method where those values are passed to functions thereafter.

The output I want : *how many  neighbours are there for a particular node*.

The code is given below with the input and the desired output for the test case

Input values

```
6
India
Pakistan
Nepal
Bhutan
Bangladesh
China
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   1
1   0   1   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0
Bhutan

Output Put 
3



class DFSUtil {

  static int search(List<Node<String>> graph, int[][] adjacencyMatrix,
          Node<String> startNode, String searchString) {//START search METHOD
      //Here i want logic 
      // USE findNeighbours METHOD TO FIND NEIGBOURS USING ADJACENCY 
      return 0;

  }//END OF search

  //DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING METHOD
  static List<Node<String>> findNeighbours(int[][] adjacencyMatrix,
          List<Node<String>> graph, Node<String> node) {
      int index = -1;
      ArrayList<Node<String>> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int idx = 0; idx < graph.size(); idx++) {
          if (graph.get(idx).equals(node)) {
              index = idx;

              break;
          }
      }

      if (index != -1) {
          for (int idx = 0; idx < adjacencyMatrix[index].length; idx++) {
              if (adjacencyMatrix[index][idx] == 1) {
                  neighbours.add(graph.get(idx));
              }
          }
      }
      return neighbours;
  }
}
//DO NOT  EDIT THE CLASS
class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private boolean visited;
    private int nodeIndex;

    public Node(T data, int nodeIndex) {
        this.data = data;
        this.nodeIndex = nodeIndex;
    }

    public final int getNodeIndex() {
        return nodeIndex;
    }

    public final boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public final void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public final T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (null == obj) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Node)) {
            return false;
        }
        Node<T> otherNode = (Node<T>) obj;
        if (this.getData().equals(otherNode.getData())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem is `BFS` but your class is `DFSUtil`

Comment: sorry It is DFS

Comment: Please replace the "Here I want logic"-part with explanation of what you already tried. BTW: The problem's style looks very much like hackerrank...

Comment: The number of neighbours is just the sum of a row or column in the incidence array, you don't need a complex search algorithm.

Comment: It was problem based questions, asked in one of my assessment test but i got fail there . Even tried some things but it was wrong. So just i want how we can implement the logical through this code only. So kindly help me out with this.

Comment: Please don't expect us to guess. Post a complete [mcve] with test data.